# Retrieve data from PHP file by ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I found a script on the net, which makes two PHP files interact.
Specifically, the first file (details.php) shows some statistical data of a football match. If the match is in progress, I show the live score by running another PHP file (live_score.php). The two files interact thanks to the following script, present in the details.php file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setInterval(function() {
   var id=<?php echo"$id"?>;
   var x = "<?php echo"$cod"?>";
   $("#risultato").load("live_score.php", {var:id, x});
   refresh();
   }, 5000);
});
```

from details.php, I call live_score.php passing it some parameters.
These parameters are used by the live_score.php file to retrieve the score and other information in real time.

To print the result on the screen in details.php, I use a simple ECHO inside the live_score.php file, but I would like to retrieve this data and the others in a different way, via ajax if possible, but I don't know if it can be done and how....can you help me please? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you have already solved half of your problem. From your code , you should first remove the "refresh()" to stop reloading the page every 5 seconds.

then make sure that the the payload is correct, because the word "var" is a reserved keyword in JavaScript.

HTML

```
<div id="risultato"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$.ajax({
url: "live_score.php",
type: "POST",
data: { id, x},
success: function(response) {

    //this response will be the data from "live_score.php"
    //now assuming that 
    // 1. you use vanilla javascript with plain html + css
    // 2. the returning reponse looks like this
    // [{"teamName": "theTeam1", "score": 10}, {"teamName": "theTeam2", "score": 10}]
    
    //Clear the current score
     $("#risultato").empty();
     
    // Now iterate through the response, 
    $.each(response, function(index, item) {
    
        var teamName = item.teamName;
        var score = item.score;
        var html = "<p><strong>" + teamName + "</strong>: " + score + "</p>";
        
        // this code will append (add to the end) the data iterated 
        $("#risultato").append(html);
    });
    
},
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    //if your code or ajax call had any problems , 
    //you can debug here and write error handling logic here, like
    
    if(error){
         alert("failed to fetch data");
         console.log(error);
    }
    
}
```

});

Comment: Thanks for your interest.
I removed the refresh, the status is "success", but I don't get any data from live_score.php....maybe it depends on how I build the data in live_score.php...in this file I generate a text variable which I then print on screen with ECHO. How should I organize the data in live_score.php in order to display it in details.php?

Comment: you could use JavaScript Fetch API for Ajax calls. it would give you more clear picture on what is happening.

Comment: Thanks Noel. Thanks to your suggestion, I searched on the net and I solved it

Comment: Sure happy to know!